# How to create a function defining the lower and upper limit of n numbers and returning the output as number of pairs having such range

Tags: r, function, statistics, range, rstudio

I want to create a function where I want to define a list of numbers and then defining lower & upper limit accordingly. The output expected is the number of pairs under the range.

```
n = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9)
```

`q(lower limit)` =  where each i is the lower limit

`q(upper limit)` - where upper limit defined for each i

the function must return an array of q integers which fall in the range specified.

This I have tried so far,

```
jobOffers <- function(scores, lowerLimits, upperLimits){

}
```

`enter code here`

```
answer <- jobOffers(scores, lowerLimits, upperLimits)
for (i in 1:length(answer)) write(answer[i], stdout())
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? By ‘under the range’ do you mean within the range?

Comment: By range I  mean, the the output should be under the lower limit and upper limit defined in the function.

Comment: Sorry, that is still ambiguous. Higher that the lower limit and lower than the upper limit?

Comment: Is it `seq(lowerLimits, upperLimits, by = 1)` that you want?

Comment: So basically this is a test, wherein I want to know how many students fall within the defined lower and upper limit. So the output what I want out of the function is number of students falling in the defined range, and hence will be offered jobs.

Answer (score 0):

using base functions it would be:

```
length(which(n > min(n) & n < max(n)))
[1] 6
```

If you intend to wrap in a function it would be:

```
students <- function(x){
  length(which(x > min(x) & x < max(x)))
}

students(n)
[1] 6
```

If the lower and upper bounds are fixed across all your vectors you wish to test, say if you're using the function column-wise, then you can set them as variables:

```
upper_limit <- 9
lower_limit <- 1
```

and use those in the function:

```
students <- function(x){
  length(which(x > lower_limit & x < upper_limit))
}

students(n)
[1] 6
```